# Does `pgrep` have a way to exclude child processes?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a script called `testscript.sh`.  I'm trying to use `pgrep` to count how many instances of the script are running:

```
pgrep -fc testscript.sh
```

I don't know how to exclude child processes and always end up with a count that includes them.  For example, when I run a simple script I end up with a count of `2` instead of `1`.  Using `pstree` to check the PID, I get this:

```
sshd(4073)───bash(4074)───bash(21948)─┬─bash(21959)───sleep(22220)
                                      └─tail(21958)
```

PID `21948` is from me running `./testscript.sh`.  PID `21959` is from calling `tail` in the script.  Is there a way to get `pgrep` to exclude everything to the right of the `bash(21948)` process?

Comment: I guess this would be more suitable on [unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

- try not using `-f` since that tracks the whole command line as a pattern
- use `-x` to match only on the exact command
- anchor your `-f` using `^` or otherwise use a more specific regex pattern with it
- use `-P 4074` but that requires you to know the parent process ID ahead of time.  you can nest another pgrep if you know the pattern to get the parent ie `ps -c -P $(pgrep parent) script`

Comment: Trying to find rfcomm and NOT krfcommd, pgrep -x rfcomm was what I needed.  Thank you.